# Apache recvfrom latency

Tags: php, apache

Have been trying to troubleshoot if some sort of php script (or something else) is causing apache to serve websites after 5-7 seconds. Soon as a request is made for a certain website, it takes a few seconds just to get it. I can't seem to figure it out.

To troubleshoot I did a strace on a telnet localhost to see what is causing the latency. This is what showed up, but I can't seem to find any information on it?

```
5.004994 recvfrom(3, "", 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = 0
```

What is that? Why does recvfrom take 5 seconds? I was hoping to get pointed to a php script or something....but it ended up being recvfrom.

This is what was before the recvfrom, a select command. Assuming maybe a mysql command took the longest?

```
6360       0.000056 select(4, [0 3], [1], [3], {0, 0}) = 1 (out [1], left {0, 0})
6360       0.000045 write(1, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nDate: Tue, 18 Nov 2014 03:08:19 GMT\nServer: Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fip$
6360       0.000056 select(4, [0 3], [], [3], NULL) = 1 (in [3])
6360       5.004994 recvfrom(3, "", 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = 0
6360       0.000053 rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {SIG_DFL, [TSTP], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f38e1c666a0}, {0x7f38e26196f0, [TSTP], SA_RE$
```

Comment: I don't think that says that `recvfrom` took 5 seconds. It says that `recvfrom` was called 5 seconds after the process started. So the **previous** function took 5 seconds.

Comment: This is what was before the recvfrom, a select command. Assuming maybe a mysql command took the longest?

6360       0.000056 select(4, [0 3], [1], [3], {0, 0}) = 1 (out [1], left {0, 0})

6360       0.000045 write(1, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nDate: Tue, 18 Nov 2014 03:08:19 GMT\nServer: Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fip$

6360       0.000056 select(4, [0 3], [], [3], NULL) = 1 (in [3])

6360       5.004994 recvfrom(3, "", 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = 0

6360       0.000053 rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {SIG_DFL, [TSTP], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f38e1c666a0}, {0x7f38e26196f0, [TSTP], SA_RE$

Comment: This trace is on the server, not client. It says that the server sent its response to the HTTP request, then waited for the client to send another request. The client sent something 5 seconds later.